# Opencart (Weight issue total weight show in grams how to convert in kg)

Tags: php

I've an issue in `opencart` when I click on `shopping cart` then `net weight shows in gram like this`Shopping Cart  (1,550.00g)` .

But I want to display weight in `kg`.

how can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Just multiple by `1 000` and `round`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
<?php
$weight = number_format($weight / 1000, 2);
?>
```

Change $weight to the actual variable name. You can change the '2' at the end to however many decimal places you want to display also.

Comment: You can edit it through the View in: \catalog\view\theme\YOURTHEME\template\checkout\cart.tpl and adding the code to where it says "echo $weight;"

Comment: Just to clarify, replace "echo $weight;" with "echo number_format($weight / 1000, 2);". Hope this helps!

Comment: @ AdamskiFTW show weight 0.00 and not display unit.when apply this echo number_format($weight / 1000, 2);"

Comment: @ AdamskiFTW http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart like this after adding item then click on shopping cart weight show in kg but in my case show in grams? how can i correct this ?

Comment: Did you change the Weight Class to KG? I can give you some php code to change the weight it outputs to the cart page into KG, but the system will still be using grams as the weight measurement, which will cause problems if you use weight based shipping methods. You really need to set the Weight Class to KG in the admin panel.

Comment: yes i want to change net weight in kg not change the product weight u will give me some code of cart in controller and cart.tpl files thanks.

Comment: I've just tried with the following code and it works fine for me, make sure your products actually have a weight attached to them: echo number_format($weight / 1000,2) . " kg";

Answer (score 2):

There is an option along with each product called **Weight Class**. This is there also in **shop settings**.

Probably in shop settings the value selected for Weight Class will be grams. Change that to Kilograms and everything will work the way you want.

See [image] :

Cheers

Comment: No i want to change net weight in kg after adding 3,4 products then click on sopping cart weight show in grams not in kg how to convert this  Shopping Cart (1,550.00g)`

Comment: @Cheers i want to show net weight in kg not is grams after adding products click in shopping cart weight show in grams how to change it??

Comment: Go to admin->settings-> choose your shop, then there is an option  there like Weight Class. Change that to kg. and it should work for you..:)...

Comment: @cheas 4 types of unit stord in sytem->localization-weightclass units are g,kg,ounces,pound but issue not solved it thinks its a back end issue.what do u say ?? plz help i will stuck on this issue.

Comment: Again :-> Go to Admin->Settings->Local->Weight Class. From that drop down choose Kilogram. Then click Save button at top.

Comment: @cheas in my end no drop down only check box click on check box no effect i have already tell u in weight class 4 unit  added.